# Download uploaded file before refreshing web page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to download uploaded file in my database before refreshing the web page. I mean, when I upload file with form, I want to download it without refreshing.
In my result now, when I click to download it, I download the last file before inserting the new one where I did refresh after inserting it.

Note: I can download it after refreshing the page.

The form use jquery function to submit the form contains the file to upload. 
Maybe the problem is in `downloadtd.php?td_id=".$tdid` where the value of `$tdid` is not the correct one.

I know my problem is a little bit complicated to understand. I hope that you can help me. So,please let me know if you didn't understand my problem exactly.

```
<?php
$query="SELECT * from td where d_id=$id";    
$res=mysqli_query($conn,$query);    
if(mysqli_num_rows($res)) {    
    while($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {    
        $tdid=$r['td_id'];
        ?><div class="new">
            <a id="io<?php echo $id ?>" href="<?php echo"downloadtd.php?td_id=".$tdid ?>">
                <span id="tdt<?php echo $tdid ?>">
                    <img src="images/des3.png" width="15px" height="15px">&ensp;&ensp;
                    <span  style="font-size: 13px"></span>
                </span>
            </a>
        </div><?php     
    }    
} else {
    $query="SELECT * from td where d_id=$id order by td_id desc";
    $res=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    $r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
    $tdid=mysqli_query($conn,$sq);
    ?><a id="io<?php echo $id ?>" href="<?php echo "downloadtd.php?td_id=".$tdid?>" style="text-decoration: none;" ></a><?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Please clean up your code.

Comment: Your code is likely vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or [P
DO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements as described in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/
how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: your `$tdid` is an array i guess

Comment: @Lacrioque It's done

Comment: @MancharyManchaary $tdid is the id of each row, is not in array